# swap files in swifMQ

Tags: jms, message-queue, messaging

We are using SwifMQ as the JMS infrastructure in our product. In the routerconfig.xml file there is an entry like   swap path="./store/swap"/. I wanted to understand when these swap files are created in store/swap. In the customers environment we are seeing swap files under /store/swap with names like  hostname-xxx.swap

My assumption is that SwiftMQ uses some datastructure to store  messages to be sent. This data-structure might get filled up as it is not able to send those messages because of network issue etc. I presume that in this scenario it will write to swap files. Is my assumption correct?

Any information on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Swap is used to store non-persistent messages when the queue cache is full.
if you go to sys$queuemanager swiftlet's queues properties you can see how many messages are configured to store in cache. (default is 500) 
if the producer produces over 500 non-persistent messages and the consumer has not consumed, the messages will be written to the .swp file, if the messages are persistent they will always be written to the store/db/page.db directory